# Can not access a cell in Excel using VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that is trying to compare specific data based on a tag number in the first column of an Excel spreadsheet in two different workbooks. When I am trying to access the first workbook, it works great, and I can access the data in the cell properly, with the following command:

```
s_WS_string = Workbooks(s_WS_Filename).Sheets(s_WS_SheetName).Range(s_WS_col & s_WS_row).Value
```

Where `s_WS_col` and `s_WS_row` are defined strings in the VBA script. This command successfully retrieves data. However,

```
OURS_string = Workbooks("OURS.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(s_OURS_col & s_OURS_row).Value
```

Does not. `s_OURS_col` and `s_OURS_row` are both strings as well. `WS` stands for worksheet, which is the variable worksheet being compared against the static `OURS.xlsx` sheet.

They are both the exact same command, being passed the exact same type of parameters, and yet one retrieves data from the cell, while the other does not. I'm in the process of replicating it in another environment for upload if it comes down to that.

The two strings are meant to be compared to each other, and if they dont match, to concatenate and output in a replicated worksheet. Based on my output, and my own debugging, I have found that it will find the value on the first spreadsheet, but on the static spreadsheet `OURS.xlsx`, even when it access a cell that contains the exact same data, it will remain empty, and thus be considered to not match.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Edit 1: Clarified some problems.

Edit 2: I understand that both workbooks must be opened in order to access them in this manner, and I assure you both are opened during the running of the script.

Edit 3: I have stepped through the script up to the point where it is passing the arguments to access the values. I have checked the values in both of the cells being passed, and they do match, but one is not being pulled from the workbook properly.

Comment: What does the second command do instead of getting the cell value?  Any error message?

Comment: No error message. It's just outputting as if there when I check it while debugging, there is. I've been working on a replication, but while in the process I'm running into extra bugs that I'm dealing with, so I haven't replicated it yet. I will continue working on it, and will post the sheets when I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong with at least one of your variables. I recreated your case with 2 workbooks, Book1 and Book2, and added a value in cell A1 of Sheet1 in each. The code runs fine.

```
Sub TestCellValueFromWBs()
    Dim s_WS_string, Ours_string As String
    s_WS_string = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value
    MsgBox s_WS_string

    Ours_string = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value
    MsgBox Ours_string
End Sub
```

Step into your code (F8) and check the values of the variables and make sure they are pointing to the correct objects.

Comment: They are both pointing to  two different cells that contain the exact same data, i stepped through (ctrl-f8) until I hit a specific cell being passed, and double checked by looking up the exact address being passed at that particular point in time, and  it's just that one sees nothing, and the other does. I'm almost done recreating it, I'll have it up in a bit.

Comment: I apologize for not getting back, uploaded to a friend of mine who troubleshooted it for me, and found out that there was a discrepancy in how I was accessing the cells, when accessing a workbook that was opened but not active, the question was resolved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries -- glad you got it to work. Thanks for updating what happened.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6Si6shEN is the complete code for future reference. Still a work in progress, but you see the general idea.